# Interfacing C structure in Python

Tags: python, c, struct, ctypes

I have troubles using a DLL function with Python. I need to use a specific DLL written in C for my application. I can't modify the DLL but I have the definitions of the structures. So the C structure is like this :

```
typedef struct {
    int length;
    int* val;
        //to access value at a row => val[row]
} Array1dInt, **Array1dIntHandle;
```

and the prototype of the function is :

```
void __declspec(dllexport) modifywithHandle(Array1dIntHandle);
```

I have defined my class in Python like this :

```
class Array1dInt(Structure):
    _fields_=[("length",c_int),("val",c_int)]
    def handle(self):
        """Return a pointer. Use this function when you need the Handle of the array structure"""
        return addressof(pointer(self))
    def __init__(self,vec):
        """init initialize an object of the class Array1dInt. Takes a python array as input"""
        self.length=c_long(len(vec))
        self.vector=np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(np.array(vec))
        self.val=c_long(addressof(self.vector))
```

When I want to use the DLL function I do it like this :

```
Python_array=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
MyObject=Array1dInt(Python_array)
modstruct=DllLib.modifywithHandle
modstruct.argtypes=[c_int]
modstruct(MyObject.handle())
```

Among other stuff, I should see the length and the element in the console. The DLL function retrieve the length correctly but is unable to read the vector. I have tried different solutions with pointer or addressof, but nothing seems to work. I have noticed that length and val are not converted to ctypes object whereas vector is.
Assuming that the DLL function is coded correctly, what am I doing wrong in Python ?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Where is your doe for Structure in python?

Comment: `("val",c_int)` is wrong. It is `POINTER(ctypes.c_int)`

Comment: Also, `addressof(pointer(self))` is wrong... how do you think you can *read this* value after modification if you don't store it anywhere!

Comment: One question: why did you introduce *numpy* into the equation? It only adds an useless level of complexity.If you browse [\[SO\]: Questions tagged \[ctypes\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ctypes), it's very likely that you'll find one it's very close (if not identical) to yours.

Comment: Marcus.Aurelianus : what do you mean by doe ?
Antti Haapala : I tried with pointer, the problem was that it creates a new instance in memory and when I sent it to the DLL, it was the address of the pointer instead of the content of the pointer variable that was sent. And a question, why would addressof(pointer(self)) change its value at each iteration ?
CristiFati : I used numpy to convert the vector to a ctypes vector. And for an unknown reason, it is the only attribute that do show up as a ctypes element, i don't know why but MyObject.length returns 6 instead of c_int()

Comment: Also why is `Array1dIntHandle` a double pointer?